# Flex 4: Controls in spark Panel still show when outside of panel size

Tags: apache-flex, controls, panel, visible

I discovered this while doing some programmatic panel resizing:
   Components in a spark Panel will still be visible when their location is outside the physical Panel boundaries.   This does not happen with the mx Panel.

Running Flex 4.1 on Windows 7

I tried putting mx and spark controls in the spark Panel, and they both appear outside of the boundaries.   Note this doesn't happen with the mx Panel.

What am I missing to make the spark behave like the mx?

Thanks !

Sample Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Panel x="6" y="8" width="157" height="200">
        <s:Label x="2" y="10" text="ABCDEFGHIJKL" width="258" height="35" textAlign="right"/>
        <mx:Label text="Label" x="232" y="55"/>
        <mx:Button x="125" y="96" label="Button"/>
    </s:Panel>
    <mx:Panel x="10" y="216" width="200" height="200" layout="absolute">
        <mx:Label x="0" y="46" text="Label" width="217" textAlign="right"/>
        <mx:Button x="163" y="88" label="Button"/>
    </mx:Panel> 
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I don't have time for an in depth look.  But, there is some overflow property that relates to scrolling, I think it is clipAndEnableScrolling.  If you don't explicitly set that property to 'true' the content is not clipped at the end of the the panel.  You'll also have to manually add a scrollbar to many Spark components, I'm not sure if a Panel has it built in or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Kodiak provided the same path, so I feel even more confident in that answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may put a `s:Group` in them and set `clipAndEnableScrolling="true"`. It's quite similar to CSS's `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Kodiak:  Your prompt answer is very appreciated.  This solved my problem.